# Let $G$ be a finite group and $S$ set of generators. Show that every element of $G$ can be written in form $x_1...x_n$ where $x_i\in S$.

Tags: group-theory

I know what does set of generators mean and that subset of $G$ generates some subgroup. But I have no idea how to prove the statement above in title. It's like comes from definition and there is nothing to prove.

Comment: The group generated by $S$ is the set of elements of the form $x_1\cdots x_n$ where $x_i$ or $x_i^{-1}$ belongs to $S$, so the problem is to show that $x_i^{-1}$ can be written as a product of elements of $S$.

Comment: @Dan Let $S$ be a subset of a group $G$, having at least one element. Let $H$ be the set of elements of $G$ consisting of all products $x_1...x_n$ such that $x_i$ or $-x_i$ is an element of S for each $i$, and also containing the unit element. Then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, called the subgroup generated by $S$. We also say that $S$ is a set of generators of $H$.

Comment: You could just show that in a finite group G, if $x \in G$, then $x^{-1}$ is a (positive) power of $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the set $H$ of products of elements in $S$. This is nonempty and is closed under multiplication. (Note: if $S$ is empty, then $H=G=\{1\}$.)

**Theorem.** *If a non empty subset $H$ of a finite group $G$ is closed under multiplication, then it is a subgroup.*

Hint for the proof.

Show that $1\in H$. Fix an element $x_0\in H$ and consider the map $f\colon H\to H$, $f(x)=x_0x$. Then $f$ is injective, so it's also surjective and so $x_0=f(x)$ for some $x$.

Next, there is $y\in H$ such that $f(y)=1$ (because $1\in H$ by the previous argument). So…

Now, since $H$ is a subgroup containing $S$, since $S$ is a set of generators of $G$, we have $H=G$.

Comment: $1\in H$ since by definition generator has a unit element of $G$. $f$ is injective because  $x_0x_1=x_0x_2$ we can multiply from left side with $-x_0$ since $x_0$ in $H$ implies that $-x_0$ is also in $H$ by definition.$f$ is surjective since for every $x'$ we have $x_0x=x'$ for some $x$ because $x',-x_0\in H$ implies $x=-x_0x'\in H$. So the reason for constructing function $f$ is to show that $H$ is subgroup containing $S$.
1)Am I right?
2)Why do we have implication that you expressed in the last sentence?
3)Does it happen often solution of group problems requires considering a functions

Comment: @Mihail Not really good. Since $f$ is injective (your argument is good), it is also surjective *because* $H$ is finite. Then there is $x\in H$ such that $f(x)=x_0$, which means $x_0x=x_0$ so $x=1$, hence $1\in H$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering to my own question and I'd like to know if it's acceptable. By definition generator set $H$ generates a group $G$ if $H\subset G$ and every element in $G$ equal to some finite product of elements of $H$ and inverses of these elements. So it is only necessary to show that $x^{-1}$ can be expressed as product of $x_1...x_k$ where $x_i\in S$.

Since $G$ is finite $x^m=y=x^l$ for some $m>l$. So $x^{m-l-1}=x^{-1}$ and we are done.
I'd like to have your strict judgement of my proof.